# Bluetooth Mouse

Tags: drivers, gentoo, bluetooth

Why can't I connect the following mouse:

```
# lsusb
...
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 19ff:0239 Dynex
...
```

Device 2, the controller, is working fine, after some googling with the Hex ID(See [Answer: Firmware Update](https://askubuntu.com/a/632348/267913) to see how I got it working, in case you're curious.  Here is where I'm stumped.  Using [Gentoo Bluetooth Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Bluetooth) and the [Arch Bluetooth Mouse](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/bluetooth_mouse) pages, the following is the output I get from `blutoothctl`:

```
# bluetoothctl
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# list
Controller BC:14:EF:65:E9:62 bedroom-gentoo [default]
[bluetooth]# show  BC:14:EF:65:E9:62
Controller BC:14:EF:65:E9:62 (public)
    Name: bedroom-gentoo
    Alias: bedroom-gentoo
    Class: 0x001c0104
    Powered: yes
    Discoverable: yes
    Pairable: yes
    UUID: Generic Attribute Profile (00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX File Transfer        (00001106-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Generic Access Profile    (00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: OBEX Object Push          (00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: PnP Information           (00001200-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: A/V Remote Control Target (0000110c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: IrMC Sync                 (00001104-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Notification Se.. (00001133-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Phonebook Access Server   (0000112f-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    UUID: Message Access Server     (00001132-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
    Modalias: usb:v1D6Bp0246d0531
    Discovering: yes
[bluetooth]# select  BC:14:EF:65:E9:62
[bluetooth]# power off
Changing power off succeeded
[CHG] Controller BC:14:EF:65:E9:62 Powered: no
[CHG] Controller BC:14:EF:65:E9:62 Discovering: no
[CHG] Controller BC:14:EF:65:E9:62 Class: 0x00000000
[bluetooth]# power on
[CHG] Controller BC:14:EF:65:E9:62 Class: 0x001c0104
Changing power on succeeded
[CHG] Controller BC:14:EF:65:E9:62 Powered: yes
[CHG] Controller BC:14:EF:65:E9:62 Discovering: yes
[CHG] Controller BC:14:EF:65:E9:62 DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
[CHG] Controller BC:14:EF:65:E9:62 DiscoverableTimeout: 0x00000000
[bluetooth]# agent on
Agent is already registered
[bluetooth]# default-agent
Default agent request successful
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
Changing discoverable on succeeded
[bluetooth]# pairable on
Changing pairable on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[NEW] Device 34:88:5D:87:C7:CE Bluetooth Mouse M336/M337/M535
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:87:C7:CE Connected: no
[DEL] Device 34:88:5D:87:C7:CE Bluetooth Mouse M336/M337/M535
[NEW] Device 34:88:5D:87:C7:CE Bluetooth Mouse M336/M337/M535
[CHG] Device 34:88:5D:87:C7:CE Connected: no
[DEL] Device 34:88:5D:87:C7:CE Bluetooth Mouse M336/M337/M535
```

Notice the NEW, CHG, and DEL lines for the Bluetooth Mouse M336/M337/M535 (I receive the NEW, CHG,and DEL lines only when pressing the pairing button).  Every time I attempt to connect trust or pair the item, I receive:

```
[bluetooth]# pair 34:88:5D:87:C7:CE
Device 34:88:5D:87:C7:CE not available
```

---

I'm trying to convert my peripherals to Bluetooth to save my front side usb ports.  I don't dare try my new headphones until after I have a working mouse.

I looked at the packaging today, and the mouse is officially packaged as the [Logitech M535 Bluetooth Mouse](http://support.logitech.com/en_za/product/bluetooth-mouse-m535/specs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, I missed a step in the Bluetooth Wiki.  Added my user to the plugdev group with:

`usermod -a -G plugdev ecyoung`